# How to perform an action after 24h? (not using setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Discord bot that has a punish command, and I want to make the bot remove the punishment after 24 hours/1 day. Don't want to use setTimeout() because the bot can go down between that period and setTimeout() consumes resources. How to do that? Thank you.

Comment: `setTimeout()` does not consume meanginful resources - timers are extremely efficient in node.js.  If you want to make the timer persistent, then save your timers to disk or a db each time you start them and when they fire, remove them from the storage.  Then, each time your server starts up, it can restart any timers in the db.

Comment: The bot can go down between that period.

Comment: I don't know what your comment means.  My previous comment explains what to do when things to down and come back up.  Or, you can see my answer below that explains how to do this without timers.  I think I've given you two different ways to solve this and you've provided no feedback at all on either one.  When people provide answers, you should comment on those answers, either asking for clarification if you don't understand something or accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark if it works for you and solves your problem.

Comment: That's how this place works.  Waiting 19hrs to come back is not an efficient way (for anyone here) to use this site and is probably part of why your question received downvotes.  You need to write clear questions, be responsive when people ask clarifying questions and be responsive when people post answers.

Answer (score 0):

upon punishment, a variable can be assigned as Date.now()+86400000. When they log in and   the current Date is greater than this value, the ban will end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without timers.  When you ban the user, just mark their user object (in whatever persistent store you use for user accounts) with a date/time that the ban ends.  Then, log them out.

Then, on every login request, check the user object to see if they have a ban time and if the current time has passed the ban time. If not, fail their login (don't let them in).  If so, remove the ban time from the user object as the ban is now over and they can now login in.